# d3js: Concatenating "d.y" + year

Tags: d3.js

(This is following up on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25836145/d3js-calling-different-data-from-the-same-csv-transitions).) Super-brief/basic Q: is there any way that I can concatenate `d.(something)` with a numeric value? I'm using a CSV and my variable names follow a pattern (for year 2012 = y2012, year 2002 = y2002, etc).

I'd like to refer to the current year being examined after each keydown. For example:

```
svg.selectAll("circle")
    .transition(1500)
    .attr("r", function(d) {
    return Math.sqrt(parseInt("d.y"+year) * 0.0004);  
})
```

Console's telling me `"d.y"+year` is not kosher. I've tried defining it as a variable, testing it out in the console (where it returns `"d.y2012"`), but it still breaks the `function (d)`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In javascript, `d.something` is the same as `d["something"]`.

In your case, you can try `d["y"+year]` instead of `"d.y"+year`.